# Pin notification icon with Ionic V4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, notifications, ionic4

I'm currently working on a `Ionic V4` ( `Angular` ) project that includes Video conversation.

My purpose right now is to display a small Icon on the device's toolbar (where you can swipe down to view notificaitons) when the app is active. So that if someone leaves the app, they have a way of knowing they're still in a video conversation.

I used Notifications plugin, and when I push a notification it does display as intended, but if you clear the notification - the Icon goes away.

I've seen this feature in the `Waze` app (When you navigate somewhere and leave the app, you still have a badge on your toolbar)

Any idea how to obtain that kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

When you create a notification - You can provide properties. 
When you assign 'sticky: true' the notification will be anchored.

[LocalNotifications GitHub Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LFRd.png)